# Adding a ASP.NET button as a AsyncPostBackTrigger to an UpdatePanel in a Content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

As the title says...

I have a button in my master page. When clicked I want it to update my UpdatePanel, which in in a content page, not the master page. How to I add this button as a AsyncPostBackTrigger to my UpdatePanel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Button click event, you can do something like

```
CTYpe(ContentPanel1.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).Update()
```

Comment: Cheers Bala, just what I needed! Forgot you can do that!